# CoreFoundation CFBasicHashAddValue Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, admob, core-foundation

Recently I notice some crash reports like this. (Only on iOS 11.)

I'm not using WebView in my app. I guess it's related to AdMob. (Interstitial Ads or Banner Ads)

Is there any way to fix it?  Thanks a lot.

```
CoreFoundation CFBasicHashAddValue 
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x000000045f74beb8
(It's not in the main thread.)

Crashed: WebThread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x186278430 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x186eda330 CFBasicHashAddValue + 208
2  CoreFoundation                 0x186ef01d4 CFRunLoopAddTimer + 536
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x18e272658 WTF::RunLoop::TimerBase::start(double, bool) + 188
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d945524 WTF::dispatchFunctionsFromMainThread() + 344
5  Foundation                     0x187a06a50 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 340
6  CoreFoundation                 0x186fbe2e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
7  CoreFoundation                 0x186fbe268 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
8  CoreFoundation                 0x186fbdaf0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
9  CoreFoundation                 0x186fbb6c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
10 CoreFoundation                 0x186edbfb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
11 WebCore                        0x18ed4fe04 RunWebThread(void*) + 456
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x186c4031c _pthread_body + 308
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x186c401e8 _pthread_body + 310
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x186c3ec28 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Is there any additional info at all? This looks like something is being added to a basic hash table that either isn't an object, or has already been deallocated. Is this an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, or otherwise?

Comment: @ItaiFerber It's `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`.

Comment: Yep, looks like `0x000000045f74beb8` isn’t an object pointer. It’s either a bug in AdMob or there’s some memory corruption afoot. Not much you might be able to do about it, unless you can consistently reproduce the issue.